# adding shortcodes to functions.php - syntax error maybe?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am just toying around with wordpress and php and am stuck.

In a functions.php file in wordpress, I'm creating two basic example shortcodes using this

```
<?php

add_shortcode('addAudioFile', 'addAudioFile');
function addAudioFile( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
  return '<li class="audio_file">' . $content . '</li>';
} 


add_shortcode('addAudioPlayer', 'addAudioPlayer');
function addAudioFile() 
{
  return '<audio preload></audio>';
}
```

The first one just turns the user content into a list item, and the second just calls an instance of the plugin audio.js. As it is written,the admin panel breaks and I assume I am missing something to my syntax.

What is it??? Thanks!!!

PS one shortcode in the php file works fine, but when I add them both, it doesn't work. This is all that is in the functions file.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not allow to overwrite functions, so you can't have two functions with the same name. You need to rename the second one.